# My LCD screen has a green line down it and doesn't want to go away

Tags: display, lcd

I know it's my screen and was wondering if there is any method known to fix this apart from getting a new screen? I've plugged in a different screen on the same DVI cable and it works fine and used a different DVI cable on the same screen and the line remains, so this rules out my graphics card, that's if I'm not mistaken. Recommendations on any software that can be used to rectify this problem will be greatly appreciated, as I've grown to love my screen. It's a Lenovo D222 Wide 16:10 display 1680x1050.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Io55FZQUn8

Comment: You can always try to disassemble it and put it back together again, on the assumption that it might be a bad plug connection.  But I wouldn't hold my breath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the error is present at all times, even when the computer is loading, for example during the bios/manufacturer initial splash screen, or when booting from a live CD (maybe an ubuntu live CD or some other). Then you need to resort to technical support.

Comment: The issue is not permanent, that's why i find it so strange. The weirdest thing is that I don't notice it whilst gaming but mainly when my windows desktop is open or when working in office etc. One so called fix is to install the most recent drivers, but alas we all know the result to that one.

Comment: Have you tried updating or reinstalling drivers for both display and video card?

Comment: @AndreasSchiemann - Does it "come and go" simply because of the different colored background?  I've had LCDs with a few bad pixels where they were invisible most of the time, but painfully obvious when you put up a contrasting background.

Comment: It seems to stay and I think that the concentration on the game itself, for example DOTA2, takes my attention away from the green strip down my screen. Does this make sense in anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Bad pixels and lines are popular LCD failure modes :-(

Comment: Agreed, But seeing that there are so many of them out there, one would think that a method to repare these issues would hve been created. This I'm hoping for.